# byte [] transmission using libjitsi

Tags: audio-streaming, rtp

I would like to pass `byte[]` from source to target using **libjitsi** library. I have seen examples either using the audio stream which was generated by audio device or by audio files. I did not see any examples with byte[] transmission. Please share any links or sample code if you have.

If this is not possible then can you suggest any other library/java api where the audio `byte[]` can be transferred using **RTP** protocol.

Comment: How the audio byte[] can be transferred using RTP protocol in java, from one machine to other machine

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have found the solution, but here is what I can suggest

If the requirement is only sending byte[] via RTP, then any simple Java-RTP example lib like *[https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/teaching/ais/1998/projects/java_rtp/report.html](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/teaching/ais/1998/projects/java_rtp/report.html)* should help.

Mainly look for in sources, *SendRTPPacket(byte[] data) in Session.java*

Yes the code is quite old, needs some package restructuring if used as dependency directly but will do the job if applied